# How to save parameters and clear the url?

Tags: java, url, servlets, jakarta-ee

My aim is to provide the ability to sending comments or reviews on the site. When I get the parameter from the form they are properly added to my reviews database. But the problem is that the URL contains the paramaters. So when I fill the form and press the submit button, there are a new record in the database, but the comment is not shown on the page at once. Also when I refresh the page, the same record is duplicated in the database. I want user to fill the forms, press the button and then redirect to the same page with his comment or review. Here is my servlet doGet method code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Query query = new Query();
    Object allReviews = query.getAllReviews();
    request.setAttribute("allReviews", allReviews);

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("reviews.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

    if (request.getParameter("sendReviewButton") != null){
        String userName = request.getParameter("reviewName");
        String eMail = request.getParameter("reviewMail");
        String reviewList = request.getParameter("reviewText");
        query.addReview(userName, eMail, reviewList);
    }

}
```

And my form in jsp:

```
<form action = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Reviews" method="get">
          <p>Your name:   <input type="text" size="107" name="reviewName" required></p>
          <p>Your e-mail: <input type="text" size="90" name="reviewMail" required></p>
          <p>Your review:</p> 
          <p><textarea rows="15" cols="135" name="reviewText" ></textarea></p>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" name="sendReviewButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="send-btn">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the else statement. So the new review is correctly added, it is shown on the page immediately. When I refresh the page the record in the database is NOT duplicated:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Query query = new Query();

    if (request.getParameter("sendReviewButton") != null){
        String userName = request.getParameter("reviewName");
        String eMail = request.getParameter("reviewMail");
        String reviewList = request.getParameter("reviewText");
        query.addReview(userName, eMail, reviewList);

        Object allReviews = query.getAllReviews();
        request.setAttribute("allReviews", allReviews);
        response.sendRedirect("/ScopeSoftware/Reviews");
    }else {
        Object allReviews = query.getAllReviews();
        request.setAttribute("allReviews", allReviews);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("reviews.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you should probably use POST and not GET, so that the data is not seen on the URL and the browser warns the user if she reloads the page
2. Add the new review before you get the list of reviews, so you get the updated list
3. use sendRedirect to the reviews.jsp page so that the url is the short one. This should render point 2 moot as you're going to list the review after you've added the new one.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me to get to the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are forwarding to the JSP page, but this does not solve the refresh problem. The solution is - as you already said in your question - to redirect to the JSP:

```
response.sendRedirect("reviews.jsp"); // url of the JSP page.
```

This sends a HTTP redirect back to the browser and the browser then does a new GET to `reviews.jsp`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me to get to the solution I needed.